# Where to put the application ID in YQL

Tags: php, yql

I'm trying to read an xml response from YQL:

```
$url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20woeid%3D%22'.$woeid.'%22';

if (!$xml=simplexml_load_file($url) )
{
   //DO STUFF
}
```

This code works. Now i'm trying to put my application ID in the url string but I don't know how it should be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to do this in order to authorize your requests; for example, to receive the higher rate limits, etc.?

YQL uses [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) for authorization rather than simply adding an API key or appID into a request URL. The process is well documented and their [code examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html) covers requests using 2-legged and 3-legged OAuth in both PHP and JavaScript.

Is there any reason why the public (non-authed) service doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read thed OAuth part, but someway I thought that an auth ala Google was also possible.
I need the auth version because I want to get a lot of data and the 1000 per hour limit is not enough.